# How it's possible to disable rendering layout in case of xmlhttprequest in phalcon framework?

Tags: php, layout, controller, xmlhttprequest, phalcon

**How can be disabled layout rendering?**

For a moment i can detect that request is made via jQuery this way:

```
public function initialize()
{
    if (!$this->request->isAjax()) {
        // disable layout here... how?
    }
}
```

**Could it be done globally?**

Code for handling ajax requests will be the same for all controlles, is there a way to define this behaviour rule globally for whole application?

Comment: What is initialize? Is this in your base controller class or something?

Comment: @Koveras i have extended phalcon\mvc\controller and defined this function to handle ajax requests. Please see http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#initializing-controllers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public function initialize()
{
    if (!$this->request->isAjax()) 
    {
        // disable layout here... how?
        $this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    }
}
```

Also you could disable the auto rendering by calling

```
$this->view->disable();
```

Comment: $this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW) would be more corrert here.. but thanks a lot for idea :)